# Distributed graph DB: Performance measure

Tags: database, gremlin, arangodb, amazon-neptune, graphdb

I  wish to change DB to a graph database. I am looking for a good way to examine engines by performance.

### **What I’m looking for:**

I will have a **small number** of queries and a **large database**, so I will prefer a faster engine rather than an engine that let me throw a lot of queries.

- Ability to search by multiple properties of a Node or an Edge.
- Ability to search text.

And also how can I measure performance differences between them?

### **How I thoght to do it:**

- to set a list of queries and test it on the same data.
- Check the time each query took and calculate by my needs.

but, I think it will be very time-consumption to download the DB engine, insert the data, compose the queries, etc.

Does anyone has a better idea for checking it?

Comment: Hello. It's always nice to see people considering the use of a graph database. However, questions on StackOverflow looking for recommendations between technologies tend to get closed by moderators as they require opinion based rather than technical answers. I'm very familiar with Amazon Neptune, less so with ArangoDB. I'm happy to try and help but I suspect this question will get closed. It might be better, at least to get input on Neptune, to post your question [here](https://repost.aws/tags/TAxVAEdWg1SrS0lClUSX-m_Q/amazon-neptune).

Answer (score 0):

There's a [performance test here for ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/performance/) vs some different types of databases. The tests are from a few years back so they are a bit outdated but it might give you a clue if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using benchmarking tools like LDBC (Linked Data Benchmark Council) for standardized performance evaluation of graph database engines. LDBC benchmarks provide realistic workloads and queries, saving time compared to manual setup.